# Using a closure to generate an R6 binding

Tags: r, r6

I'm using active bindings in an R6 class to check values before assignment to fields. I thought I could use a closure to generate the bindings as below, but this doesn't work.

The binding isn't evaluated in the way I expect (at all?) because the error shows the closure's `name` argument. What am I missing?

```
library(R6)
library(pryr)

# pass a field name to create its binding 
generate_binding <- function(name) {
  function(value) {
    if (!missing(value) && length(value) > 0) {
      private$name <- value
    } 
    private$name
  }
}

bind_x = generate_binding(x_)
# created as intended:
unenclose(bind_x)
# function (value) 
# {
#     if (!missing(value) && length(value) > 0) {
#         private$x_ <- value
#     }
#     private$x_
# }

MyClass <- R6::R6Class("MyClass",
  private = list(
    x_ = NULL
  ),
  active = list(
    x = bind_x
  ),
)

my_class_instance <- MyClass$new()
my_class_instance$x <- "foo"
# Error in private$name <- value :
#   cannot add bindings to a locked environment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you’re misunderstanding how closures work. `unenclose` is a red herring here (as it doesn’t actually show you what the closure looks like). The closure contains the statement `private$name <- value` — it does *not* contain the statement `private$x_ <- value`.

The usual solution to this problem would be to rewrite the closure such that the unevaluated `name` argument is deparsed into its string representation, and then used to subset the `private` environment (`private[[name]] <- value`). However, this doesn’t work here since R6 active bindings strip closures of their enclosing environment.

This is where `unenclose` comes in then:

```
MyClass <- R6::R6Class("MyClass",
  private = list(
    x_ = NULL
  ),
  active = list(
    x = pryr::unenclose(bind_x)
  ),
)
```

Comment: This is terrific. Thanks.